# Do balls in expander graphs have small expansion?

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, geometric-group-theory, spectral-graph-theory, expander-graphs

Consider a $d$-regular infinite transitive expander graph $G$, and let $B_r$ be a ball of radius $r$ in $G$. Can one place any upper bounds on the expansion of $B_r$?

My intuition is that $B_r$ will have very low expansion, perhaps exponentially small in $r$. The reason for this is that expander graphs are locally tree-like, and finite trees -- which is what I am imagining obtaining upon restricting to $B_r$ -- are the worst possible expanders.

I am thinking in particular about the case where $G$ is the Cayley graph of an infinite discrete group with exponential growth, but would be interested in understanding the answer more generally.

Comment: How does one define the notion of expander for a single infinite graph? The definition I know is for a sequence of finite graphs.

Comment: one normally just defines the expansion as the minimum expansion of any finite region. from this definition one sees that infinite trees are excellent expanders, while finite ones are very poor expanders (hence the intuition above)

Comment: Could you give an actual definition? I know how to define an expansion constant (the Cheeger constant) for a finite graph but then what?

Comment: that is the actual definition, $\Phi = {\rm inf}_{S \, \mathrm{finite}} \Phi(S)$, where $\Phi(S)$ is the expansion of the region $S$.

Comment: This definition will give you zero for all connected graphs of bounded valence (assuming that a "region" is a connected subgraph). Where did you see this as the definition?

Comment: why? for an infinite tree you get something nonzero (of course S must be nonempty in the above definition). you can see e.g. [here](https://lucatrevisan.wordpress.com/2014/08/20/the-spectrum-of-the-infinite-tree/) for a readable introduction.

Comment: Each connected graph $G$ of infinite diameter contains a subgraph which is a ray $H$, i.e. is isomorphic to $[0,\infty)$ with nonnegative integers playing role of vertices. Now, take a sequence of subgraphs $H_n$ in $H$ of the form $[0, n]$, $n\in {\mathbb N}$. Cheeger constants of the subgraphs $H_n$ converge to zero. Hence, with your definition, the "expansion constant" of $G$ is zero. It is possible that your *expansion constant* of a finite graph  is not the same as the Cheeger constant. In any case, it is your responsibility to  edit your question to clarify your definitions.

Comment: @MoisheKohan - I believe that you and user3521569 are talking past each other. This is not helped by the fact that user3521569 gave the wrong definition for the expansion of an infinite graph. The correct definition is (I believe) given at the [link](https://lucatrevisan.wordpress.com/2014/08/20/the-spectrum-of-the-infinite-tree/) user3521569 provided.

Comment: @SamNead thanks for acting as an intermediary -- can you however help me understand what was wrong with my definition? I believe I just copied it from the provided link. I am also confused since the aforementioned $H_n$s seem to have nonzero expansion (since they have legs sticking "off" of them and into the remainder of $G$)

Comment: You did not define what you mean by "expansion of a région S". Moishe Kohan interpreted it as the Cheeger constant of the induced subgraph, whereas you apparently had something else in mind.

Comment: See this paper https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v29i2p23/pdf for a similar (open) question on sequences of finite graphs rather than infinite graphs (though infinite graphs are briefly mentioned in Section 3).

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but an intuition for an answer (suggesting that balls should have exponentially small Cheeger constant).

Suppose that $n \geq 2$.  The volume of $B^n(R)$, the ball of radius $R$ in $n$-dimensional hyperbolic space, is basically some constant (depending on $n$) times $e^{(n - 1)R}$.  In dimension one ($n = 1$) we instead have some constant times $R$.

Suppose now that $M$ is a closed connected hyperbolic $n$-manifold.  Pick a basepoint $x$ in $M$ and pick a graph $\Gamma$ in $M$ that nicely carries the fundamental group of $M$.  Lift all of this to the universal cover $M'$ to get a graph $\Gamma'$ which is quasi-isometric to $n$-dimensional hyperbolic space.  So $\Gamma'$ will be expansive, and will be roughly as expansive as balls in the ambient hyperbolic space.

So we can move interchangably between large balls in the graph $\Gamma'$ and large balls in hyperbolic space.  Let's assume that $n$ is at least three.  Now consider $B^n(R)$, the ball of radius $R$ in $n$-dimensional hyperbolic space. This is cut exactly in half by its "equatorial disk", a copy of $B^{n-1}(R)$.  The volume of half of $B^n(R)$ is roughly $e^{(n-1)R}$.  The volume of the equatorial disk is roughly  $e^{(n-2)R}$.  So the ratio is $e^{-R}$, as suggested by the original question.

---

To make these examples work, we needed a notion of dimension.  So it is not exactly clear how this generalises.

Comment: great, thanks for making the above intuition more precise. might it be possible to always find some embedding of an expander into an appropriate hyperbolic space? some googling says that ML people will occasionally due this but I did not find any rigorous results.